# AngularJS- How to use $http.post to pass multiple parametres to a server class

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services

I am new to AngularJS and web services.
I am doing a program that gets value from the user->[name and age] and insert those values to the oracle database. I only was able to insert a single value. My search for using $http.post to pass multiple values didn't turned out good.
It would be so much helpful if somebody could help.
Here's the code

**Client side code**

```
<html>

<title>My AngularJS App</title>  

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DBCtrl">
<script type ="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.co/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-submit="insertData()">
Student name: <input type = "text" ng-model="name" >
Student age: <input type= "text" ng-model="age">
<br>
<input type ="submit" value="INSERT">

</form>
<p>{{msg}}</p>

<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('DBCtrl', function($scope,$http){

$scope.insertData = function(){

    alert($scope.name);
    $http.post('rest/DB/add',$scope.name)
    //$http.get("rest/DB/extract")
    .success(function(){
        $scope.msg="DATA INSERTED";

    })
    }
    });


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Server Side Java Code**

```
package com.ustri.DBman;

@Path("/DB")
public class DBManager {

@POST
@Path("/add")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public void addDetails(String sname,String sage){
    System.out.println("IN add");

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","hr","hr");          
        //step3 create the statement object  
        System.out.println("Connection established successfully");
        PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into studreg values(?,?)");  
        System.out.println(sname+"+"+sage);
        stmt.setString(1,sname);  
        stmt.setString(2,sage);

        int i=stmt.executeUpdate();  
        System.out.println(i+" records inserted");  
        con.close(); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  


    }

    }
```

Using this code I am only able to insert a single value $scope.name.
How can I modify my code to pass both $scope.name and $scope.age parametres through $http.post to Server?

Comment: An angular application typically sends JSON, and receives JSON. You can of course send something else, and receive HTML, but this makes it harder than necessary. Why don't you just send and receive JSON?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes... that was all necessary...

Answer (score 5):

> Using this code I am only able to insert a single value $scope.name.
>   How can I modify my code to pass both $scope.name and $scope.age
>   parametres through $http.post to Server?

By default, the `$http` post/get methods transform the requests by serializing the data as JSON and post them with the `"application/json"` content-type.

 While you seem to want to post your data with the `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` content-type.

You could specify the `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` content type and create the data with the good format (adding the `&` separator between the transmit values) before sending them.

Or else you could do simpler.
You can send a JS object that contains both information.

replace

```
$http.post('rest/DB/add',$scope.name);
```

by

```
var postedObj = {'name':$scope.name, 'age':$scope.age}
$http.post('rest/DB/add',postedObj);
```

and change your rest controller according to.

Replace

```
public void addDetails(String sname,String sage){
```

by

```
public void addDetails(Details details){
```

where `Details` has as fields the two transmitted values.

```
public class Details{
  private String name;
  private String age;

  // and add getters and setters if required by your JSON/Java mapper.
}
```